# Check the Presence of String Then Copy Value from JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have been striving to find an solution that how to check if JSON has specific string `"Processing":true` if it has then copy the `"newLogno":776655` the ID.

Here is entire JSON

```
{"id":16,"sku":"4926","productName":"Diforda","upc":"test",
"condition":"test","uniqueID":1234,"logsCey":3,
"Processing":true,"addedDateTime":"2021-06-22T04:07:35.15",
"softDelete":false,"newLogno":776655}
```

If someone can please share a solution i would really appreciate.

```
Sub jsontoexcel()

Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "URL", False
http.Send
Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
i = 2
For Each Item In JSON

If  "Processing":true = "Processing":true then

Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("newLogno")

i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON only has 1 record so no need for loop.

```vb
    Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
    i = 2
    If JSON("Processing") = True Then
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = JSON("newLogno")
    End If
```